# No results when using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I just started with jquery and i am using jqwidgets. I assume all the jquery files are correct so the problem must be in my own code. There are two files, takenlijstdata.php and takenlijst.php. The first one performs the query and it displays everything correct in an array.

When i open takenlijst.php wich should give me a table with some filtering options i get an empty page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>Testpagina.</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com/jquery/scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="generatedata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // prepare the data

        var source =
            {
                localdata: data,
                datafields:
                [
                    { name: 'taaknummer', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'naam', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'taak', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'prioriteit', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'datum', type: 'date' }
                ],
                datatype: "array",
                url: 'http://www.site.com/management/takenlijstdata.php',
                async: false
            };

        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 685,
                source: dataAdapter,
                showfilterrow: true,
                filterable: true,
                selectionmode: 'multiplecellsextended',
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Name', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'textbox', filtercondition: 'starts_with', datafield: 'taaknummer', width: 115 },
                  {
                      text: 'naam', filtertype: 'checkedlist', datafield: 'naam', width: 220
                  },
                  { text: 'taak', datafield: 'available', columntype: 'checkbox', filtertype: 'bool', width: 67 },
                  { text: 'prioriteit', datafield: 'date', filtertype: 'date', width: 210, cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'd' },
                  { text: 'datum', datafield: 'quantity', filtertype: 'number',  cellsalign: 'right' }
                ]
            });
            $('#clearfilteringbutton').jqxButton({ height: 25});
            $('#clearfilteringbutton').click(function () {
                $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('clearfilters');
            });
        });
     </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id="jqxgrid">
    </div>
    <input style="margin-top: 10px;" value="Remove Filter" id="clearfilteringbutton" type="button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Again, i am new to jquery so i'm sorry if this is a strange/stupid question.

Comment: Have you tried opening up the javascript debugger in chrome or firefox?

Comment: If you can use Chrome or Firefox, watch the output in the console, also check "Log XMLHttpRequests" for debugging in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at this, I see you reference the variable "data" when you instantiate the source variable, but I do not see that "data" variable defined anywhere on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I see another problem here: 1. data is undefined and 2. you set "url" and "localdata". You should use either "url" or "localdata". Example: [jqwidgets grid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/php/grid.htm?arctic)